# Conditional display in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my index.html.erb I want to display one of two pieces of content based on a value the record has.

My splits have a column called "default" and if the content of that = 1 then I want to display a padlock icon indicating the user can't change that item. If the value is anything else I want to present a checkbox.

In my splits controller I have created "@default":

```
def index
    @splits = Split.all
    @chosen_splits = Issue.find(1).splits.order('updated_at desc')
    @split = Split.first
    @default = Split.find_by default: "1"
    # @balance = @split.balance
end
```

In my view I have the following code:

```
<% @chosen_splits.each do |split| %>

<tr>
  <td> <!-- trying to have conditional presentation -->
    <% if @default == '1' %>
    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-lock"></i>
    <% else %>
    <input type="checkbox" value>
    <% end %>
  </td> <!-- end of trying to have conditional presentation -->
  <td><%= link_to split.name, split_path(split) %></td>
  <td class="text-right"><%= number_with_delimiter(split.quantity) %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_split_path(split), :class => 'btn btn-xs btn-default' %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Delete', split, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, :class => 'btn btn-xs btn-danger' %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

From what I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795053/if-else-statements-in-html-erb-in-views) this should be working. But, it's not.

My log file is showing:

```
Processing by SplitsController#index as HTML
  [1m[35mIssue Load (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT  "issues".* FROM "issues" WHERE "issues"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[36mSplit Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "splits".* FROM "splits"  ORDER BY "splits"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mSplit Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT  "splits".* FROM "splits" WHERE "splits"."default" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["default", 1]]
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "issues".* FROM "issues" WHERE "issues"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT SUM("splits"."quantity") FROM "splits"
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT SUM("splits"."quantity") FROM "splits"[0m
  [1m[35mSplit Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "splits".* FROM "splits"
  [1m[36mSplit Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "splits".* FROM "splits" WHERE "splits"."issue_id" = $1  ORDER BY updated_at desc[0m  [["issue_id", 1]]
  Rendered splits/index.html.erb within layouts/application (7.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 625ms (Views: 620.9ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
```

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@default` doesn't contain a string with "1", it contains a `Split` object, the one where the column `default` contains "1".

Or, if it can't find that object, then it contains `nil`.

Maybe what you want to do is better done with...

```
<% @chosen_splits.each do |split| %>
    <tr>
      <td> <!-- trying to have conditional presentation -->
        <% if split.default == '1' %>
          <i class="fa fa-2x fa-lock"></i>
        <% else %>
          <input type="checkbox" value>
        <% end %>
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But, I'm still not getting the padlock to show. Checkboxes are showing for everything still. Even cleared my cache and restarted server.

Comment: and are you sure that one or more `Split` objects in `@chosen_splits` actually have a "1" in the default column? Change this to show the default value... `<td><%= link_to split.name + " default:#{split.default} ", split_path(split) %></td>`

Comment: Yes, 3 of them do. When I put that code in the 3 which I expect the padlock to display for correctly show "default:1" next to the split name.

Comment: Ok, then my next guess is that `split.default` is actually `1` not `"1"`... it's probably a fixnum, not a string.  Try `<% if split.default == 1 %>`

Comment: That's it! It's an integer. Thanks!