# How to add JavaScript based on some ruby conditionality?

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, conditional-statements

I want to add some JavaScript based on some ruby conditionality. How can i do that?

For example

```
<%= if current_user.role == "User" %>
  Adding some JavaScript here
<% else %>
```

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: I am using Ruby on Rails application

Comment: See this question, Put your JS codes in `<script>` tag. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795053/if-else-statements-in-html-erb-in-views

Answer (score 1):

```
<% if current_user.role == "User" %>
  <%= render js: "alert('Hello, world!')" %>
  <%= render 'path/to/file.js' %>
<% end %>
```